# Alamofire with custom parameter encoding for swift application

Tags: swift, alamofire

I have to call some methods from the soap web service in my swift application, so I think I should use custom parameter encoding, but when I create closure for this encoding it seems never to be called. Am I doing something wrong?

Here is my code:

```
    let custom: (URLRequestConvertible, [String: AnyObject]?) -> (NSURLRequest, NSError?) = {
        (URLRequest, parameters) in
        let mutableURLRequest = URLRequest.URLRequest.mutableCopy() as NSMutableURLRequest
        mutableURLRequest.setValue("text/xml; charset=utf-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        mutableURLRequest.HTTPBody = body
        return (mutableURLRequest, nil)
    }

    Alamofire.request(.POST, WebServiceURLString, parameters: nil, encoding: .Custom(custom)).responseString { (request, response, data, error) -> Void in
        println(data)
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `custom` closure is not executed by design, because there are no parameters to encode. He're a code excerpt taken from [Alamofire.swift source file](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Source/Alamofire.swift#L78-80):

```
if parameters == nil {
    return (URLRequest.URLRequest, nil)
}
```

As you can see, you can bybass this condition by passing an empty dictionary:

```
Alamofire.request(.POST, WebServiceURLString, parameters: Dictionary(), encoding: .Custom(custom))
```

The `custom` closure will now be executed.

Comment: Empty dictionary won't do in latest Alamofire. Parameters must contain at least one key/value pair for the custom closure to be executed. "guard let parameters = parameters where !parameters.isEmpty"