# AFNetworking with Swift give errors in LLDB

Tags: ios, swift, afnetworking

I want to use AFNetworking in the Swift app. I added it to the Podfile and importet in the bridging header file. It works but the problem is when I try to debug and use LLDB for example po to look at my variable I get this errors:

```
error: Error in auto-import:
failed to get module 'test2' from AST context:
/Users/bialek/Desktop/test2/test2/test2-Bridging-Header.h:9:9: note: in file included from /Users/bialek/Desktop/test2/test2/test2-Bridging-Header.h:9:
#import 
        ^
/Users/bialek/Desktop/test2/Pods/Headers/Public/AFNetworking/AFNetworking.h:34:13: note: in file included from /Users/bialek/Desktop/test2/Pods/Headers/Public/AFNetworking/AFNetworking.h:34:
    #import "AFURLConnectionOperation.h"
            ^
/Users/bialek/Desktop/test2/Pods/Headers/Public/AFNetworking/AFURLConnectionOperation.h:192:1: error: property with 'retain (or strong)' attribute must be of object type
@property (nonatomic, strong) dispatch_queue_t completionQueue;
^
/Users/bialek/Desktop/test2/test2/test2-Bridging-Header.h:9:9: note: in file included from /Users/bialek/Desktop/test2/test2/test2-Bridging-Header.h:9:
#import 
        ^
/Users/bialek/Desktop/test2/Pods/Headers/Public/AFNetworking/AFNetworking.h:34:13: note: in file included from /Users/bialek/Desktop/test2/Pods/Headers/Public/AFNetworking/AFNetworking.h:34:
    #import "AFURLConnectionOperation.h"
            ^
/Users/bialek/Desktop/test2/Pods/Headers/Public/AFNetworking/AFURLConnectionOperation.h:197:1: error: property with 'retain (or strong)' attribute must be of object type
@property (nonatomic, strong) dispatch_group_t completionGroup;
^
/Users/bialek/Desktop/test2/test2/test2-Bridging-Header.h:9:9: note: in file included from /Users/bialek/Desktop/test2/test2/test2-Bridging-Header.h:9:
#import 
        ^
/Users/bialek/Desktop/test2/Pods/Headers/Public/AFNetworking/AFNetworking.h:36:13: note: in file included from /Users/bialek/Desktop/test2/Pods/Headers/Public/AFNetworking/AFNetworking.h:36:
    #import "AFHTTPRequestOperationManager.h"
            ^
/Users/bialek/Desktop/test2/Pods/Headers/Public/AFNetworking/AFHTTPRequestOperationManager.h:154:1: error: property with 'retain (or strong)' attribute must be of object type
@property (nonatomic, strong) dispatch_queue_t completionQueue;
^
/Users/bialek/Desktop/test2/test2/test2-Bridging-Header.h:9:9: note: in file included from /Users/bialek/Desktop/test2/test2/test2-Bridging-Header.h:9:
#import 
        ^
/Users/bialek/Desktop/test2/Pods/Headers/Public/AFNetworking/AFNetworking.h:36:13: note: in file included from /Users/bialek/Desktop/test2/Pods/Headers/Public/AFNetworking/AFNetworking.h:36:
    #import "AFHTTPRequestOperationManager.h"
            ^
/Users/bialek/Desktop/test2/Pods/Headers/Public/AFNetworking/AFHTTPRequestOperationManager.h:159:1: error: property with 'retain (or strong)' attribute must be of object type
@property (nonatomic, strong) dispatch_group_t completionGroup;
^
/Users/bialek/Desktop/test2/test2/test2-Bridging-Header.h:9:9: note: in file included from /Users/bialek/Desktop/test2/test2/test2-Bridging-Header.h:9:
#import 
        ^
/Users/bialek/Desktop/test2/Pods/Headers/Public/AFNetworking/AFNetworking.h:40:13: note: in file included from /Users/bialek/Desktop/test2/Pods/Headers/Public/AFNetworking/AFNetworking.h:40:
    #import "AFURLSessionManager.h"
            ^
/Users/bialek/Desktop/test2/Pods/Headers/Public/AFNetworking/AFURLSessionManager.h:155:1: error: property with 'retain (or strong)' attribute must be of object type
@property (nonatomic, strong) dispatch_queue_t completionQueue;
^
/Users/bialek/Desktop/test2/test2/test2-Bridging-Header.h:9:9: note: in file included from /Users/bialek/Desktop/test2/test2/test2-Bridging-Header.h:9:
#import 
        ^
/Users/bialek/Desktop/test2/Pods/Headers/Public/AFNetworking/AFNetworking.h:40:13: note: in file included from /Users/bialek/Desktop/test2/Pods/Headers/Public/AFNetworking/AFNetworking.h:40:
    #import "AFURLSessionManager.h"
            ^
/Users/bialek/Desktop/test2/Pods/Headers/Public/AFNetworking/AFURLSessionManager.h:160:1: error: property with 'retain (or strong)' attribute must be of object type
@property (nonatomic, strong) dispatch_group_t completionGroup;
^
failed to import bridging header '/Users/bialek/Desktop/test2/test2/test2-Bridging-Header.h'A fatal parse error has occurred.  LLDB may become unstable; please restart your debug session as soon as possible.
```

Does anybody know what is wrong?

Comment: Why are you using AFNetworking within Swift. There is Alamofire for that purpose and its sufficient.

Comment: I tried but I could not make it to work with SOAP web service.
Here e.g. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26684688/alamofire-with-custom-parameter-encoding-for-swift-application)

Comment: I answered [the other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26684688/alamofire-with-custom-parameter-encoding-for-swift-application). Can this be closed now? :)

Comment: AFNetworking is supposed to be entirely compatible with Swift, just like any other Objective-C library. The problem is real - I'm also affected - and switching to another library is not the same as fixing the issue. Maybe it'd be preferable to move it to Github since it seems like a bug (in the library or the swift compiler). I went ahead and opened this: https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/issues/2488

Comment: @JakubTruhlář As stated in the readme Alamofire and AFNetworking are not mutually exclusive (and by extension it's not a replacement for AFNetworking). There are things that Alamofire can't do that AFNetworking can, e.g. Multipart form requests

Comment: Too bad the author of AFNetworking completely ignores the issue.  I opened a bug there too and he said there's no issue and closed the incident.

Comment: This issue has been fixed with [this commit](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/commit/3a1785ccccbd0489dc7bf937d577b6f7ca89cacf). Make sure the version you're pulling has this code.

Comment: For what it's worth, I was getting a similar issue w/ another pod in a Swift project and simply trying again worked.  For instance, `po someVar` prints out an error, then I just run `po someVar` again and it works.  Annoying to have to do things twice the first time, but at least you can debug your app in the interim.